# For loop just... not starting?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

This is a bizarre problem.  I've got a void function that performs a for loop and nothing else, but the for loop doesn't ever start, even though the function is being called.  Here is the function:

```
void Cell::Consolidate()
{
    cout << "Consolidating (outside)...\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < m_Tiles.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << "Consolidating (inside)...\n";
        int row = m_Tiles[i]->GetRow();
        int col = m_Tiles[i]->GetCol();
        //Check below.
        if((*m_pTileMap)[row + 1][col].pParentCell != this)
        {
            m_EdgeTiles.push_back(m_Tiles[i]);
            m_Tiles[i]->SetColor(sf::Color(100, 100, 100));
            bool newNeighbor = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < m_Neighbors.size(); ++j)
            {
                if(m_Neighbors[j] == (*m_pTileMap)[row + 1][col].pParentCell)
                {
                    newNeighbor = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(newNeighbor)
            {
                m_Neighbors.push_back((*m_pTileMap)[row + 1][col].pParentCell);
            }
        }
        //Check above.
        else if((*m_pTileMap)[row - 1][col].pParentCell != this)
        {
            m_EdgeTiles.push_back(m_Tiles[i]);
            m_Tiles[i]->SetColor(sf::Color(100, 100, 100));
            bool newNeighbor = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < m_Neighbors.size(); ++j)
            {
                if(m_Neighbors[j] == (*m_pTileMap)[row - 1][col].pParentCell)
                {
                    newNeighbor = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(newNeighbor)
            {
                m_Neighbors.push_back((*m_pTileMap)[row - 1][col].pParentCell);
            }
        }
        //Check the right.
        else if((*m_pTileMap)[row][col + 1].pParentCell != this)
        {
            m_EdgeTiles.push_back(m_Tiles[i]);
            m_Tiles[i]->SetColor(sf::Color(100, 100, 100));
            bool newNeighbor = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < m_Neighbors.size(); ++j)
            {
                if(m_Neighbors[j] == (*m_pTileMap)[row][col + 1].pParentCell)
                {
                    newNeighbor = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(newNeighbor)
            {
                m_Neighbors.push_back((*m_pTileMap)[row][col + 1].pParentCell);
            }
        }
        //Check the left.
        else if((*m_pTileMap)[row][col - 1].pParentCell != this)
        {
            m_EdgeTiles.push_back(m_Tiles[i]);
            m_Tiles[i]->SetColor(sf::Color(100, 100, 100));
            bool newNeighbor = true;
            for(int j = 0; j < m_Neighbors.size(); ++j)
            {
                if(m_Neighbors[j] == (*m_pTileMap)[row][col - 1].pParentCell)
                {
                    newNeighbor = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(newNeighbor)
            {
                m_Neighbors.push_back((*m_pTileMap)[row][col - 1].pParentCell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, `"Consolidating (outside)...\n"` gets send to cout, but `"Consolidating (inside)...\n"` does not.  Nothing that is supposed to happen in the loop actually happens, either (for example the SetColor() calls don't do anything, nor does anything happen if I send things to cout anywhere else in the loop), so I can only assume the loop is not starting at all.  Why not?  What could cause this?

Comment: What prevents you from Debugging the code and analyze what's happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
i < m_Tiles.size()
```

This loop condition gets checked on *entrance* to the loop, not only after each iteration. If your `m_Tiles` vector is empty, well, no loop for you.

Comment: Darn... that means the problem is somewhere else.  I need to pay more attention when porting my Python code to C++. Shame, I thought I had stumbled across some deep, esoteric idiosyncrasy of C++. :P

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `m_Tiles.size()` returns a negative value or zero value.

Comment: What's a negative size? It's 0, if anything.

Comment: If it's a personal crafted class, it is possible.

Comment: No, negative size never makes any sense.

Comment: I will kill anyone who returns a negative value for something that represents size. Thought I'd put that nicely.

Comment: @Marlon: Just demand a `size_t` for anything that represents a size, can't get negative. :)